# Calling function from the same controller to return the view with flash message

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

When the user save the object in the blade view, a function into my controller execute with post request. If the save was success I want to reload the page with the changes.

So I need to call index() again to get the refreshed data. Also, I want to show a success message. So the steps are:

1. index() function execute so the user can show his items.
2. the user choose an item and save it
3. save(Request $request) is called
4. everything save fine
5. save function call index() with sending a parameter with the flash success message?

I have this structure in my controller:

```
public function index(){
   ...
   return view('agenda')->with(['agenda'=>$response]);
}

public function save(Request $request){
   ...
   // here where I need to return index function with success message
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `save` action was called from the index page, simply redirect back

```
public function save(Request $request){
    ...
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Item saved');
}
```

If it was called from a different page, redirect to index page. Assuming your `index()` function matches a route `/`:

```
return redirect()->to('/')->with('message', 'Item saved');
```

Then display the `flash message` in your index view.

```
@if(Session::get('message'))
    {{ Session::get('message') }}
@endif
```

For styling, if you are using bootstrap you can do

```
@if(Session::get('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Works, but the message is a plain text, do not have style

Comment: I added some styling for you. Check my answer again for updates.

Comment: Works like a charm, Eddy!